# Comparing performance after CV over a single dataset : does it violate the independence assumption?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, independence, paired-comparisons

Cross validation lets us get multiple estimates of the generalization performance of an algorithm when the performance cannot be estimated for each example independently.  (As with an F1-score, we need to estimate it over all of the data.) But when we use a t-test to determine whether or not there is a difference in performance between the two algorithms, we need to make an assumption that the estimates are independent. Do estimates derived from cross-validation violate this independence assumption?