# Statistical comparisons of multiple classifiers performance?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, t-test

If the accuracy of $classifier1$ is statistically significantly better than $classifier2$ as per some hypothesis test, and likewise the accuracy of $classifier2$ is  statistically significantly better than $classifier3$, does it follow that $classifier1$ is  statistically significantly better than $classifier3$. This question relates to my question asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45851/how-to-statistically-compare-the-performance-of-machine-learning-classifiers).

Comment: I believe you made a typographical error and wish to ask (in shorthand notation) whether $c_1 \ge c_2 \ge c_3$ implies $c_1 \ge c_3$. The answer depends on what you mean by "statistically better." Be careful how you answer that!--a natural meaning of "better" in this context is closely related to [Efron's nontransitive dice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice).

Comment: I reviewed the question.

Comment: You still have that typo. After all, if $c_1$ is better than $c_2$ and $c_3$ also is better than $c_2$, you still have no information to compare $c_1$ to $c_3$: you only know there is something worse than both.

Comment: blond moment. yes.

Comment: by statistically better I mean the accuracy of one is better than the other by some hypothesis test.

Comment: OK, but you need to be more specific: what data would you be using for the tests? (The correct answer might depend on whether you use independent sets of data for the pairwise tests or a common set of data for all pairwise tests, or whether you conduct a simultaneous test of all classifiers.)

Comment: Accuracy of each classifier estimated by cross validation on same same dataset.