# Statistically significant comparison of classifiers

Tags: classification, statistical-significance, cross-validation, method-comparison

I am working on a movie review sentiment analysis project, and comparing various classifiers  on the same dataset. The data for the two classes is balanced, so I'm using accuracy on 3-fold cross validation as the basic measure of performance.

How can I check whether one classifier is better than another, with statistical significance? Is this a test I can do directly on the accuracy values, or do I need multiple accuracy values (from the multiple folds), or even individual classifications for each instance of data? Is the pair test applicable here?

Details:
Dataset: 1000 positive, 1000 negative reviews. Bag of unigrams (words). 
Classifiers: Naive Bayes, SMO and LogReg
Evaluation: Single accuracy percentage at the end of 3-fold stratified cross validation for each of the classifiers.

Answer (score 1):

This question on CV [How to statistically compare the performance of machine learning classifiers?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45851/how-to-statistically-compare-the-performance-of-machine-learning-classifiers) might help you. I recommend the literature pointed out by in the second (accepted) answer.